# Wordpress: make a post's video URL accessible from the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for solution to a particular situation. In my theme each post is on a single page (single.php). Single page has a slider inside of the loop that is populated with attachment images. In that slider, I need to add some videos that are hosted on  YouTube. 
What I think I need is to write a plugin that allows to add YouTube URLs to a post in UI input fields in post editing window. These links would be then accessed using post id from single.php, so that I could loop through them, using foreach and render them as as html5 video.

I need a general advice on how this can be done. I've got a working slider that needs to host these videos along attachment images, but using attachment video does not work and it doesn't seem to be a viable solution (it's bandwidth intensive).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this out using a simpler approach, namely, I've used shortcodes to wrap content that's in the slider. It worked fine and saved plenty of time; it's more intuitive in comparison to using image attachments for creating the content, too.